# Matrix size error when trying to use the BLUP for calculating breeding values

Tags: r, matrix

My screen in R studio

[image]

I am trying to use raw data to calculate breeding values using BLUP. The methods I have done before worked, but now I am encountering the error that you can see in the picture above. This is my code so far.

```
pdgedit <- 
  editPed(sire=newdata$SIRE, dam=newdata$DAM, 
          label=newdata$ID)
ped <- 
  with(pdgedit, 
       pedigree(label=label, sire=sire, dam=dam))

y <- matrix(gen21sex$GNAW)
y
X <- matrix(gen21sex$SEX)
X
Xo <- matrix(0,253,2) 
for (i in 1:253){
  Xo[i,X[i]] <- 1
}
Xo

zeros=matrix(matrix(0,31878),ncol=126)
zeros
eye=diag(1,253)
eye
Z=cbind(zeros,eye)
Z

A <- getA(ped)
A

A_ <- getAInv(ped)

A_ %*% A


sig2A=3.2
sig2E=12.8

# Variances of error terms
R=diag(sig2E,253)
R
# Inverse of R:
R_ <- solve(R)
R_

# Variance/covariances of breeding values. 
# ( <- means 'equal to' in R) 
G <- A * sig2A
G
# Inverse of G:
G_ <- solve(G)
G_

# Making Mixed Model Equations: 
XRX <- t(X) %*% R_ %*% X
XRZ <- t(X) %*% R_ %*% Z
ZRX <- t(Z) %*% R_ %*% X
ZRZ <- t(Z) %*% R_ %*% Z 
ZRZG <- as.matrix(ZRZ+G_)
```

The last line was an attempt at a fix with the original code being

```
ZRZG <- ZRZ + G_
```

The only issue I can think of is with the zeroes bound to the Z matrix, but I created it as I've done before. The total observations (from new data) - the observations in the y matrix (from gen21sex) so (379-253=126) which 126 is the number of columns and there will be 253 rows for each observation in y so 126*253=31878 total zeroes bound to a 253x253 identity matrix creates the Z matrix.

I am still working hard to understand how to create breeding values in R and how to use BLUP, but this is how I have always done it and any assistance would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: It may be useful if you used one of the package datasets so that the example is reproducible, and it will probably make it a bit easier to get help.